# Difference of full codebook and non full codebook

Tags: cryptanalysis, algebraic-attack

While reading a paper about Dynamic cube attack, I saw two terms:
**full-codebook** and **non-full-codebook** attacks.
What do they mean?
What is the difference?

Regards

Comment: A reference to the paper in question would be useful.

Comment: https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/040.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In **full codebook**, data complexity equals to all input of cryptosystem and in **non full codebook** is less than it.

For example in SIMON 32/64, if data complexity=2^32, the attack is full codebook,
and if DC < 2^32, the attack is non full codebook.